# Is it possible to find a specific row in a dataframe using only 2 known variables?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I'm trying to get the row that contain the maximum value. I have 2 variables: sw_col which contains the value of 'sharewomen' column and max_sw which contains the maximum value in the 'sharewomen' column. 'sharewomen' is a column which is part of a dataframe called recent_grads.

here is a look at sw_col:

```
0      0.120564
1      0.101852
2      0.153037
3      0.107313
4      0.341631
5      0.144967
6      0.535714
7      0.441356
8      0.139793
9      0.437847
10     0.199413
11     0.196450
12     0.119559
13     0.310820
14     0.183985
15     0.320784
16     0.343473
17     0.252960
18     0.350442
19     0.236063
20     0.578766
21     0.222695
22     0.325092
23     0.292607
24     0.278790
25     0.227118
26     0.342229
27     0.322222
28     0.189970
29     0.251389
         ...   
143    0.606889
144    0.423209
145    0.779933
146    0.444582
147    0.506721
148    0.845934
149    0.667034
150    0.752144
151    0.810704
152    0.910933
153    0.697384
154    0.798920
155    0.905590
156    0.904075
157    0.745662
158    0.728495
159    0.584776
160    0.383719
161    0.719974
162    0.968954
163    0.707136
164    0.967998
165    0.690111
166    0.629505
167    0.666119
168    0.637293
169    0.817099
170    0.799859
171    0.798746
172    0.877960
Name: sharewomen, Length: 173, dtype: float64
```

Is it possible? How do I do it?

Comment: `recent_grads[ recent_grads["sharewoman"] == max_sw ] ` ?

Answer (score 0):

In case your column has only one row, you can type following...
recent_grads.max() and it will do the trick.

Or

recent_grads['sw_col'].max()

Comment: EDIT: you can create a new column and assign in a single statement: recent_grads['max_sw] = recent_grads['sw_col'].max()